# global name 'localset' is not defined

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I get this error.

> global name 'localset' is not defined

Following is my code.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from forms import SignUpForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form= SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
    save_it=form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    return render_to_response("signup.html", localset, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The variable localset is really not defined. I cannot add anything to what the interpreter is saying. :(

Comment: It's not really clear why you thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of code:

```
return render_to_response("signup.html", localset, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

The variable **localset** is not defined.

Comment: yes thats the problem i removed local set now it is showing the template 'signup.html' does not exist

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as answer.

Comment: it is just explanation it did not solved my problem sorry@ amin a

Answer (score 0):

@Amin A answer is correct for your original question. You do have a variable set within the `render_to_response` function which is not defined within your view function.

You should change the `render_to_response` line to look like this:

```
return render_to_response(
    'signup.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

There is something which you should be aware of here also. According to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) the use of `context_instance` has been deprecated since django 1.8.

> **Deprecated since version 1.8:**
>   The context_instance argument is deprecated. Use the render() function instead which always makes RequestContext available.

You should now be using the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) function if you are passing back a context.
This will now mean you code will look something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import SignUpForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form= SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it=form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
    return render(request, "signup.html")
```

Comment: thanks amin a it solves my problem but my login page comes empty after it...i found the answer which worked for me by changing 'localset' to 'locals()'

Answer (score 0):

from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from forms import SignUpForm

## Create your views here.

def home(request):
    form= SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it=form.save(commit=False)

```
    save_it.save()
return render_to_response("signup.html", locals(), context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```